# CSS aligning 3 items one by one

Tags: html, css

I need to align three elements given below as horizontally instead of vertically... Here is the current file... How can I do it?

HTML:

```
    <div id="banner">
        <div class="IE-banner">
            <div id="go-lang">
                <p> This will contain google language </p>
            </div>
            <div id="go-search">
                <p> This will contain google search </p>
            </div>
            <div id="go-search">
                <p> This will contain facebook links </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#banner{ 
 width:900px; 
 height:75px; 
 background-color:Red; 
 color:White; 
 font-size:10px; 
 font-weight:bold; 
 position:relative; 
}

div.IE-banner{
    position:absolute;
    vertical-align:middle;
    top:20px;
    right:10px;
    font-size:medium;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Before addressing your question....It looks that there is a duplicated element id in your code. ("go-search")

Answer (score 0):

make the items you want in a line: `display:inline-block`

```
.IE-banner div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

---

to be more organized though, I would add a class to all the elements you want inline. And modify only that class.

```
<div id="banner">
    <div class="IE-banner">
        <div id="go-lang" class="inline">
            <p> This will contain google language </p>
        </div>
        <div id="go-search" class="inline">
            <p> This will contain google search </p>
        </div>
        <div id="go-search" class="inline">
            <p> This will contain facebook links </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.inline {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
.IE-banner
{
float:right;
background-color:red;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by changing the display property of the elements. This also allows you to avoid excessive divs in your code:

```
<ul class="banner">
    <li>Google lang</li>
    <li>Google search</li>
    <li>Facebook</li>
</ul>
```

With the CSS rules:

```
ul.banner       { display: block; }
ul.banner > li  { display: inline-block; }
```

Or using a floated method:

```
ul.banner       { display: block; overflow: auto; }
ul.banner > li  { float: left; }
```

Nice and clean with HTML content suitable for various media.

Answer (score 0):

I show you here 2 alternatives trying to keep in line with your markup design
[image]

Details are at your will to manage.

I modified one of the ids to avoid duplicated id in your markup (New id named **"go-face"**)

```
<div id="go-face" class= "goDiv">
                <p> This will contain facebook links </p>
  </div>
```

I modified your IE-banner rule in order to center vertically your text and get rid of extra code

```
div.IE-banner{
   text-align:center;
   line-height:75px;   
   font-size:medium;
}
```

I named "goDiv" to a class shared by all your divs nested in IE-banner and added  a rule targeting this class  which will floats the divs and set for them a third of available width

```
.goDiv {
    width:33.33%;
    float:left;
}
```

Example can be seen at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fico/BdkuS/)

**Alternative**
If you dont want to add a class to nested divs you could modify the selector as follows and will work as well

```
.IE-banner div{
   width:33.33%;
    float:left; 

}
```